# Only allow registrations from specific email domains

Tags: asp.net-mvc, regex

I am developing a site that uses the built in account model / controller that comes with the new MVC site template. I want to be able to only allow people to register if they use one of two specific domains in their email address.

So for example they can register if they use @domain1.co.uk or @domain2.co.uk, but no other domains (for example Gmail, Yahoo etc) can be used.

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If using the MVC3 default site, you'll have a `/Models/AccountModels.cs` file. You can add a regular expression there to cause client-side* and server-side validation.

```
public class RegisterModel
{
    ...

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "Email address")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+(@domain1\.co\.uk|@domain2\.co\.uk)$", ErrorMessage = "Registration limited to domain1 and domain2.")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

You will need to work out the expression that works out best for your requirements.

**client-side validation assumes your view references the jquery.validate script and has `Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)` and/or `Html.ValidationSummary()`, which it should by default.*

Comment: Thanks Justin, this was the solution for me. It works perfectly. Thanks to all you other guys who posted answers.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Might as well use the built-in functionality, right?

Comment: Thanks Justin. This saved me time.

Comment: @tnktnk Cool! Glad this helped.

Answer (score 4):

What more do you need than:

```
if( email.Contains("@domain1.co.uk") || email.Contains("@domain2.co.uk") )
     Register(email);
else
    throw, return false, whatever()
```

Answer (score 1):

Validate that on both the frontend (the reg form) and the backend.

Here I recommend [jquery validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) for client side validation.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes time to do your validation, i.e. is the email field populated, use a regex to make sure it is in the domain. As for what the actual regex should be, there is a lot of discussion online about validating email addresses with them. It even comes down to what a valid email address should contain. I found this example online, but it likely by no means the best solution, as I am not a regex expert. I have tried it with a few examples but I'm sure you can come up with some that will pass when they shouldn't:

`^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@mail.com$`

Where `mail.com` is the domain you want to check against. If you have multiple domains, you can either extend the regex or do multiple checks replacing `mail.com` in the regex with whatever else you want to use.

BTW I found that regex on this [forums.asp.net](http://forums.asp.net/t/1555002.aspx/1) post which touches on an issue like yours.