# .NET MVC Model Attribute Validation

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am doing a MVC application, which includes registering function. Model takes many attributes, for example. I only want to accept several domains of emails given (for example only gmail). How do I validate it?

```
 [Required]
 [EmailAddress]
 [Display(Name = "Email*")]
 public string Email { get; set; }
```

Comment: I think this will help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554524/only-allow-registrations-from-specific-email-domains

Comment: Xamthi is right, the answer is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554524/only-allow-registrations-from-specific-email-domains